# multiple nested subqueries to access outer table column?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In mariadb (but the same applied to mysql i suppose) I have the following query:

```
select 
tblrelation.id,
(     
      select count(C.id) 
      from tblcontract C 
      where C.relation_id IN(
            (
                select B.relation_id from tblrelation_branch B where B.parent_id = tblrelation.id
                union 
                select B.parent_id from tblrelation_branch B where B.relation_id = tblrelation.id
                union 
                select tblrelation.id
           ) 

      )
) as qty   


from tblrelation
```

This query works fine.

My question is about the usage of "tblrelation.id" in the double nested query in this example.

I read that "MySQL forbids referencing outer-level columns deeper than one level of nesting" ref: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198455/user-parent-table-id-in-nested-subquery.

Elsewhere I read "It is not possible to access an outer table from a derived table (simplifying a bit, this is any "subquery" that requires an alias), ref: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198455/user-parent-table-id-in-nested-subquery

Could someone explain to me the rules for both mariaDb and Mysql (should they differ) when a (n-level nested subquery) can access the (most) outer table, and when not?

Comment: Anything not working with the given query? Are you facing any error message?

Comment: In both MariaDB and MySQL allow subqueries to access columns from outer tables when properly correlated. The key is to ensure that the subquery's logic is tied to the outer query's rows through appropriate column references or aliases.

Comment: @nico. The query works fine. No error. It's just that I want to understand the rules for n-nested subqueries because for example the first link mentions that subqueries can only reference to their parent only which would seem to conflict with my sql-syntax

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone explain to me the rules for both mariaDb and Mysql (should they differ) when a (n-level nested subquery) can access the (most) outer table, and when not?

SQL is declarative language. This means that the order in which the query is processed is not similar to the query text.

In your particular query. The server may loop over nested subquery execution - in this case you will have double-nesting reference, and query will fail due to unknown identifier. But the server may optimize the query execution and divide your inner UNION to 3 separate subqueries combined on the outer (UNIONed) or intermediate (ORed) execution level. In this case selecting the value from outer table is a constant, and excess nesting level will be removed which results in correct query execution.

Moreover, the tables statistic chhange may result in execution plan changing, and the query which was successfully executed previously may somewhen fail. You cannot predict does the nesting level will be processed or removed during execution plan building. So you must think that this won't be done.

Comment: Would a stored procedure be safer than? How would I convert this query iusing a stored procedure? (i don't think it's possible with a function?)

Comment: Wouldn't the "Correlated Subqueries"-rule apply in this case? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html .  There it mentions: subquery contains a reference to a column of t1, even though the subquery's FROM clause does not mention a table t1. So, MySQL looks outside the subquery, and finds t1 in the outer query.

Comment: @Patrick No, RM tells about single nesting only.